# Display a read-only GenericForeignKey value in Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a Django model with a generic relation to either a `User` or an `Organization`. The model looks like this:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    # ...
    client_type = models.ForeignKey(
        'contenttypes.ContentType',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        limit_choices_to=(
            models.Q(app_label='users', model='user') |
            models.Q(app_label='organizations', model='organization')
        )
    )
    client_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    client = GenericForeignKey('client_type', 'client_id')
    # ...
```

I can display the name of whatever is the client of this project in the project admin list, using:

```
@admin.register(models.Project)
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        '__str__',
        'client',
    )
```

However, I can't find a simple way to display the name of the client in the actual change page of a project. I tried the obvious:

```
fields = (
    'name',
    'client',
)
```

But this generates an error about `client` not being a valid field name. I read the [Using generic relations as an inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline) section of the Django docs, but their example seems...backwards?

I just want to display the name of whoever is the client, it doesn't have to be editable. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you add `client` to `read_only_fields`?

Comment: @dirkgroten: Apparently it was that easy...! :D Don't know why I didn't think of that. Please add it as an answer and I'll happily accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `list_display` automatically treats all fields as read-only. But in order to show a `GenericForeignKey` field in the change page, you need to explicitly make it read-only:

```
read_only_fields = ('client', )
```

The error you're getting is admittedly quite disconcerting, it also tripped me a few times.

Comment: Is there anyway to add a link to the object (`client`) change form?